# Passing and returning ColdFusion Structure via JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, data-structures, coldfusion, components

I have a ColdFusion session variable that's a structure of data.  My goal is to execute a jQuery call that does one of two things via Ajax:

1. sends that ColdFusion structure to a ColdFusion component method, updates an element of that structure with a newly created string, and returns that same structure back.

or

1. executes a ColdFusion component method that creates a new string, returns that string, and assigns that new string to an element of that same ColdFusion session structure after the Ajax call.

I would think it'd be easy, but I've been having some problems.  Anybody know what I would need to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, the CF session structure and jQuery operate in two different spheres - CF on the server and jQuery in the browser.  In order to "send that ColdFusion structure to a [cfc]..." from Ajax, you'll have to have serialized the session structure as a json string and then transmitted that json string to the client somehow.  Most likely, you'll want to do this as part of the rendering of the page to the client:

```
<cfoutput>var jsonStruct = #SerializeJSON(session.myStruct)#;</cfoutput>
```

Then you can use the `jsonStruct` variable from your jQuery code as needed (as a real JS object).  When you need to send it back to CF, you can serialize it again on the Javascript side, like so:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "foo.cfc?method=myMethod", 
   dataType: "json",
   data: {myStruct: JSON.stringify(jsonStruct)}, 
   success: function (respJSON) {
      jsonStruct = respJSON;
   }
});
```

Note that you should include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to do the serialization, since some browsers *cough*IE*cough* don't support `JSON.stringify()` natively.

*Update*

I've updated the example jquery code to show how you can update the javascript object to use the response from the CFC.  To work properly, your CF will need to look something like this:

```
<cffunction name="myMethod" access="remote" returnFormat="json">
  <cfargument name="myStruct" type="string">

  <cfset var realStruct = DeserializeJSON(arguments.myStruct)>

  <cfset session.myStruct = realStruct><!--- or whatever you want to do with it at this point --->

  <cfreturn session.myStruct>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: So I use SerializeJSON to create that jsonStruct to send to the CF component.  JSON.stringify makes it a structure in CF correct?  When I return the structure back in the success, how do I assign the changed session structure back to the current session structure on the original page?

Comment: SerializeJSON is a CF function that takes a CF object and renders it as a string.  JSON.stringify is a javascript function that takes a javascript object and renders it as a string.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you go back and forth between the CFC and jQuery.

Comment: That's really cool!  However, the return value "respJSON" is the cfreturn "session.myStruct".  And respJSON gets assigned to jsonStruct.  How do I assign the coldfusion session variable that structure?  Ajax makes a separate call to the coldfusion component, and that session variable ends up being different than the one currently used.  So how can the updated session structure get assigned after the Ajax call in the success?

Comment: The coldfusion session variable gets assigned within the CFC.  Take a look at the line that I have with the comment.  That line is "assign[ing] the coldfusion session variable that structure" (meaning the structure from JavaScript).