# Delete file using Coldfusion via jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I am trying to delete image files, after populating data about the file in a modal.

My jQuery looks like this:

```
const deleteMedia = () => {
    const url = '../../includes/delete-media.cfc?method=deleteMedia';
    $(document).on('click', '.confirm-delete', () => {
        const fileName = $('.modal-wrapper').find('.file-name').text();
        $.ajax({
            url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'fileName=' + fileName,
            dataType: 'json',
            success(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error(status) {
                console.log(status.statusText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
};

export default deleteMedia;
```

And my Coldfusion file `delete-media.cfc`:

```
<cffunction name="deleteMedia" access="remote" returnType="any" returnformat="json">
    <cfargument name="fileName" >
    <cfset requestBody = toString( getHttpRequestData().content ) />
    <!--- Double-check to make sure it's a JSON value. --->
    <cfif isJSON( requestBody )>
        <cfset VARIABLES.DeleteFileName = deserializeJSON( requestBody )>
        <cffile
            action = "delete"
            file = "C:\pathToSite\img\#variables.DeleteFileName#"
        >
        <cfdump var="#variables.DeleteFileName#">
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

This is sending `fileName = fileName` as data when I check in the Network panel, and returning a 200, although I cannot see contents of the cfdump.

I am OK with the FE, not so hot on CF, my guess is that my CF is overly complex but also not doing what I hope it would do. I did try and reference some stuff I wrote a while back, plus this:

[How to use Ajax to pass Javascript variables to Coldfusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706441/how-to-use-ajax-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-coldfusion)

And this:

[Passing and returning ColdFusion Structure via JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541260/passing-and-returning-coldfusion-structure-via-jquery/9541365#9541365)

Any ideas?

Comment: Yea that CFML is pretty old school. My first thought is that you don’t need to use a .cfc. Simplify the endpoint and make it a .cfm file. Return whatever you want to the front end by outputting SerializeJSON(myReturnStruct) and then you can debug by either looking at the return data in your Ajax success callback or you could use WriteLog(). You should not need to make a call to getHttpRequestData(). All your form fields will be in the Form scope in your endpoint. Good luck.

Comment: The approach that I used to take before I retired was to start by getting the CF code to work in a standalone file.  Then I would put it in a cfc and get it to work when calling the function from CF.  Calling it from JS would be the last step.  By the way, when calling CF code from JS, you will never see the contents of a `cfdump`.

Comment: Thank you. I did actually go over to https://cffiddle.org/ to do a little debugging.

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that this should not be handled with a CFC. On the contrary, I think it absolutely should use a CFC. Using a.cfm for an AJAx call is 'old school'

Comment: @ScottStroz can you outline the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this is still problematic that you're passing a file name as part of the request. Someone can get in there are wreak havoc with your files. Are you verifying that the file in question should even be accessible by the logged-in user? What if they pass in the value of someone else's file? This also seems vulnerable to a path traversal attack. If you pass in `filename=../../someReallyImportaintFile', will that be deleted? owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal

If this is a personal site and not a business site, there's probably not much to worry about. If this was a client's site, I'd be more concerned.

In Windows, I have Steam installed here:

```
`D:\Steam\`.
```

I can open this path in Windows Explorer:

```
`D:\Steam\bin`.
```

I can also open this path,

```
`D:\Steam\bin\..\config`
```

which lists `D:\Steam\config`

If I fish around with

```
`deleteFileName=..\..\Windows\some\folder\someFile`
```

I might be able to delete files from your Windows directory if your server permissions aren't set up to prevent CF from deleting anything on the server.

Your CF user should not be the server's admin account, There are [lockdown guides](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/cc/us/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf-starter-kits/coldfusion-2021-lockdown-guide-1.1.pdf) that can help prevent all kinds of security attacks.

Ideally, you would store a list of your files in a database table and then reference a FileID as your delete request parameter.

```
$(document).on('click', '.confirm-delete', () => {
    $.ajax({
        url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'fileID=' + $('#SomeHiddenField').val(),
        success(data) {
            console.log(data);
            hideOverlay();
        },
        error(status) {
            console.log(status.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

Then, on the server, in best case scenario you verify

- is the user logged in?
- do they have access to this file?
- do they have permission to delete this file?
- Delete the physical file
- Mark the record as deleted with the time it was deleted and by whom.

Comment: Thank you for this, I am still digesting it. I would like to adopt these policies even if I am just accessing a part of my site that only I can get to.

Answer (score 1):

OK following from Redtopia's comment, I created this:

```
<cfset requestBody = toString( getHttpRequestData().content ) />
<!--- Double-check to make sure fileName exists. --->
<cfif len(requestBody)>
    <cfset deleteFileName = requestBody.split("=")[2] />
    <cfoutput>#deleteFileName#</cfoutput>
    <cffile
        action = "delete"
        file = "C:\pathToSite\img\#deleteFileName#"
    >
<cfelse>
    <cfoutput>fileName not correct</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Then in my ajax call I removed dataType json.

```
$(document).on('click', '.confirm-delete', () => {
    const fileName = $('.modal-wrapper').find('.file-name').text();
    $.ajax({
        url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'fileName=' + fileName,
        success(data) {
            console.log(data);
            hideOverlay();
        },
        error(status) {
            console.log(status.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

Seems to work OK!

Comment: Yeah, this is still problematic that you're passing a file name as part of the request. Someone can get in there are wreak havoc with your files. Are you verifying that the file in question should even be accessible by the logged in user? What if they pass in the value of someone else's file? This also seems vulnerable to a path traversal attack. If you pass in `filename=../../someReallyImportaintFile', will that be deleted? https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal

Comment: It is on a part of my site that is passworded and only I have access to. However I am all ears if there are better or more secure ways to achieve what I want. The thing I was doing before these was uploading or deleting via ftp so this is a huge improvement.

Comment: The file path in `file = "C:\pathToSite\img\#deleteFileName#"` I have truncated it actually points to a specific directory on my server, but are you suggesting that if someone traverses up the tree and guesses a folder and filename they could delete it? I don't understand how anyone can manipulate the filepath in cfml they cannot access if it is sent from the server, unless I am missing something. I don't know much about hacking.

Comment: @lharby Since this is coming from the CF server, it will be performed as the CF user. If CF can access a directory, then files in that directory can be manipulated. Unless you limit the CF account's access. When dealing with file manipulation, it's important to keep in mind the context you're performing the action from and the permissions allowed to that context. Also, if there is a password protected part of your site, you can't rely on the fact that you are the only one with the password, or that it will always be you using that password. Defense in Depth is still a good concept.